# Does it make sense to store it in blockchain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, storage

I was looking for an idea to build on Substrate and I found out this product built on Ethereum: https://create.request.network/

In a few words is an invoice system that creates/pays invoices between two actors.

My question is: Does it make sense to store the invoices(date/status etc) in the blockchain?

Thank you

Comment: For indirect questions and opinion based discussion, try asking on https://forum.polkadot.network

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb question to ask when choosing what makes sense to store on-chain is:

- Does the chain logic need this data, or just people?

If it's only that people need to read the data, it is usually better to store it somewhere off-chain, and provide a link to the data, as well as its cryptographic hash, which can be used to verify the data. Where it gets stored off-chain might be something like [Crust Network](https://crust.network/), which is tied into the parachain ecosystem.

Also, if data is very small, it might make sense to store directly on-chain.

In your particular case, let's look at it through this framework:

- date: This probably needs to be on-chain for dispute resolution, and identifying nonpayment a certain date after the invoice was issued.
- status: This definitely needs to be on chain, if you want the chain to be able to enforce anything about the contract.
- invoice breakdown: Off-chain. Often there might be a document detailing exactly what constitutes the invoice, and this is a large amount of data.

Comment: I am asking myself If I need to store (the date and status) on the chain because the cryptographic hash is proof that an invoice is already paid or not.

Do you think is a good idea to develop on the substrate?